# I recently entered Thailand from Laos and was allowed to stay for 30 days without visa. Can I do it one more time?

Tags: visas, thailand, laos, vientiane

I recently entered Thailand from Laos and was allowed to stay for 30 days without visa. Can I do it one more time?

Hello,

I haven't been in Thailand for a few years. I recently entered the country visa free from Laos (land crossing) and was allowed to stay in Thailand for 30 days.

Can I cross the border to Laos and come back to Thailand the same day and get another 30 days? I have not previously received more than one visa free stay in Thailand this year and there are no Thai visas in my current passport.

(The passport is issued by the Swedish embassy).

Vesa

Answer (score 1):

If your country is visa free for Thailand you can enter and go back again, keep in mind that if you do that a lot of times may they start to ask you questions about your travel plan.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Land borders:

Visa Exempt (VE) entries for certain nationals are [limited to twice per calendar year](http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/961219-visa-exempt-entries-now-30-days-at-border-crossings-no-more-15-days/) for nationals that qualify for VE. Malaysians are exempted from this rule.

[image]

> ### Airport borders,

No official limit.  There was an alert that would go off after 6 VE entries within a 12 month period.  But unofficially, that limit has seemed to drop to 2-3 entries since 2019, especially if you have a "history" of using VEs/SETVs over the past 12-24 months to stay.